# How can I get an HtmlElementCollection from a WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack, htmlelements

My old WinForm application used HtmlElementCollection to process a page

```
HtmlElementCollection hec = this.webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
```

In WPF WebBrowser, there are several things that are different. For example

**this.webbrowser.Document** does not have any method called **GetElementsByTagName**

Therefore my code is unable to get an HtmlElementCollection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` and then you need to cast document as `mshtml.HTMLDocument`. After you do that you should be able to use `getElementsByTagName()` method

```
 var document = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement element in inputs)
 {

 }
```

`getElementsByTagName()` returns `mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection` and each item is of a `mshtml.IHTMLElement` type

**EDIT**

Alternative solution, if you need to use WinForms `WebBrowser` you can use that instead of the WPF one. Add reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration` and `System.Windows.Forms`, create namespace in XAML and use different browser control

```xml
<Window ...
    xmlns:winforms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <winforms:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have methods which accept HtmlElementCollection as a parameter. Will this IHTMLElement be the same as HTMLElement?

Comment: No, it won't. It's different type

Comment: so can I just swap HtmlElementCollection with IHtmlElementCollection and everything should just work?

Comment: @softwareisfun check my update. Don't know if it will be so easy as I don't know how you use it. You can also use WinForms implementation

Comment: I tried that but I never added a reference to WindowsFormsIntegration

Comment: For WPF follow this tutorial(http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/), at least to get the browser running