# C# WebBrowser Document write and ExecCommand

Tags: c#, .net

while trying to convert HTML to RTF through Below Code

```
string html = "...."; // html content
RichTextBox rtbTemp = new RichTextBox();
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("about:blank");
wb.Document.Write(html);
wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
rtbTemp.SelectAll();
rtbTemp.Paste();
```

here  **Document.Write(html);** and **Document.ExecCommand**  getting error here Which `using` required to overcome this am new to this Please guide us

example: `using System.Windows.Controls;`

here is full code  [image full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is7MW.png)

Comment: _"getting error here"_ - read [ask] and show the actual error, as wel as what you've tried.

Comment: here is full code https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is7MW.png

Comment: Why don't you just right click (or `Ctrl+.`) on the errors, select _Quick actions and refactoring_ and add the using statement it suggests?

Comment: sir @CodeCaster  showing error like :   CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no accessible extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: there is now own WebBrowser class

Answer (score 0):

You're using the WPF WebBrowser control.

Instead of `System.Windows.Controls` use WinForms: `using System.Windows.Forms;`

Or see [How can I get an HtmlElementCollection from a WPF WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972874/how-can-i-get-an-htmlelementcollection-from-a-wpf-webbrowser) and [How to get HTML from WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910837/how-to-get-html-from-webbrowser-control), cast WebBrowser.Document to the appropriate type, or host the control in your WPF window.